# Relation between starvation freedom and bounded waiting

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, mutual-exclusion

I have four questions regarding the relation between starvation and bounded waiting.

1. Does starvation-freedom imply deadlock-freedom?

   My answer:

   From [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67406/does-deadlock-imply-starvation?noredirect=1&lq=1), the definition of starvation free is

   > **Freedom from Starvation** -:Every thread that attempts to acquire the lock eventually succeeds
   >
   > **Freedom from Deadlock** -:f some thread attempts to acquire the lock, then some thread (not necessarily the thread referred to in the if statement; emphasis added) will succeed in acquiring the lock.

   So I can state that **starvation-freedom imply deadlock-freedom**
2. Does starvation-freedom imply bounded-waiting?
3. Does bounded-waiting imply starvation-freedom?
4. Does bounded-waiting AND deadlock-freedom imply starvation-freedom?

I am stuck at point 2,3,4.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71703/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42871471/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2):

**2**.Does starvation-freedom imply bounded-waiting?

`Starvation` means that a thread will wait indefinitely. But `starvation-freedom` means the thread will not wait forever and will eventually get the resource. `Bounded waiting` means there is a limit to the number of times the threads are allowed to enter their `critical sections` after a thread has made request to enter its `critical section` and before that request is granted. So, its clear that `starvation freedom` implies `bounded waiting`, otherwise, some other thread can always be in `Critical section` and that contradicts `starvation-freedom`.

**3**.Does bounded-waiting imply starvation-freedom?

The answer is also yes because after the limit is crossed the waiting process will get the chance to enter `critical section` and therefore, no indefinitely waiting and therefore, `starvation-freedom`.

**4**.Does bounded-waiting AND deadlock-freedom imply starvation-freedom?

It is clear from the above explanation that it is also true.